# Attaching spring api doc to eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on spring framework.I want to attach spring api doc in eclipse.I have tried many things like going to Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries and putting the location of documentation in each jar file.But nothing works I get the following message whenever I hover cursor over any method/class.
"This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found".
Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

you must not use a jar. You can use a link to the online documentation. For Spring API. The current versionhttp://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/

In eclipse, click to the project -> build path -> configure build path. Under Libraries choose the spring libraries, open it and click to Javadoc location -> edit. Add the link or the jar-File. Validate and ok.

Link to the jar http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/

Cheers

Comment: About which spring library you are talking about.Actually what I have done is I have added all the jar files that were present in libs folder of spring framework by clicking on Add external Jars so I cannot see any spring library.Please give a solution